# Azure EntityFrameWorkCore 6.0 エラー string.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, entity-framework

VisualStudio Ver 17.4.2 で簡単なAzureデータベース入出力するフォームを作成しました。

Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022　拡張機能でインストーラーを作成してインストールしてアプリを実行し、Azure上のデータベースから以下のコードで取得しようとするとエラーが発生しました。

```
 using (var mc = new MyContext_BasicIO())
            {
                var MM = ModelManager.Current;
                MM.msg = "";
                try
                {
                    var n = 1;
                    if (Datas.Count > 0) { Datas.Clear(); }
                    Datas.Add(new Master_Person());
                    foreach (var serch in mc.Master_Persons)//←■この行でエラーが発生する。
                    {
                        n++;
                        Datas.Add(serch);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MM.msg += ex.Message;
                }
   
　         }
```

エラーメッセージ

```
string.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient
```

##### アプリの仕様

ターゲットフレームワーク：.NET6.0
ターゲットOS：Windows
ターゲットOS：バージョン7.0
Nugetパッケージ
EnityFrameworkCore.Design 6.0.13
EntityFrameworkCore.sqlserver 6.0.13
Prism.Wpf 8.1.97
RectiveProperty.Wpf 9.0.0-pre202301080724

##### Azureデータベースの仕様

場所：Japan East
価格レベル：汎用目的 - サーバーレス: Gen5、1 vCore
エラスティックプールではない

エラーからEntityFrameworkCoreをAzureのプラットフォームがサポートしていないととらえられますが、問題はVisualStudio開発中のデバック実行(Releaseも含め)では正常に取得、データ登録までできるのですが、インストール後のアプリでのみエラーが発生します。

以上のような問題が発生しておりまして作業が止まってしまいました。
不足情報があればご質問いただけると幸甚です。

もし解決策がおわかりになる方いらっしゃいましたらお手数ですがご教授願います。

**追記**

エラーメッセージはメッセージボックスに表示するようにしていたので画像添付します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

StackTrace でエラーメッセージを表示させると以下のメッセージが表示されます。

```
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.<>c.<get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled>b__7_0(String cs)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.GenerateCacheKey(Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
   at BasicIO_ClassLibrary.M_Master_Person.Get_Datas(Boolean AddNewData, Boolean IsDisplayAll) in F:\BasicIO\BasicIO\Master_Person\M_Master_Person.cs:line 33
```

Comment: 誰コメントを消したのは？